# Selected features with a join are identified improperly from a service

Tags: arcgis-server, attribute-joins, services, identify

We couldn’t figure out why a service fails to provide correct identification for the selected feature. However, the scenarios below may highlight the issue:

1. In the “UrbanMasterPlans_**WithJoin**.mxd” file, the attribute table of the “UrbanMasterPlans_PNA_Approved” layer is joined with the “Regulations” table, then the ArcGIS Server fails to identify all the selected features.

[image]

[image]

2. In the “UrbanMasterPlans_**WithoutJoin**.mxd” file, the attribute table of the “UrbanMasterPlans_PNA_Approved” layer is not joined with the “Regulations” table, then the ArcGIS Server is able to identify all the selected features.

[image]

[image]

Here is data link to test the problem:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/ev5wthdiijhp51n/PublishingIssue.zip

What might be the issue here? Why does the join affect the Identify results when applied in a service?

Comment: First, your two points in the question read the same right now (both say 'if it is joined'). Second, I note the missing values in the top scenario are the same as a value that is there - so you get the same value three more times when it 'works'. I think; there may be a subtlety in the Arabic script (which may also be an issue) I'm missing. This would indicate there may be relationship issue in your Join. I don't know how a service impacts it, but there are some issues with one-to-many and many-to-many Joins - see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002n000000

Comment: Thanks Chris, but i tried to change the display so identify displays English fields but the problem is the same, the word " Residence C " should be identified 4 times but the result  ArcGIS identified it just one time !

Comment: Apologies for the confusing way my comment was written. I meant that I am not familiar with Arabic script, so that the values looked the same to me but I might have been missing something. But based on your response, my guess is that the issue is with the join. As pointed out in the help file I linked to, in most cases a one-to-many join will only return the *first* found matching record and discard all others. This might explain why with the join you only see it once, but I haven't worked with services and don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but why the identify with join works before publishing the service and when i publish it identify fails to return the similar values and return one of them, i think its not about the join i think its ArcGIS server issue. thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bug in ArcMap 10.2 and ESRI already fixed it in ArcMap 10.3